# Integration: find as an exact value the enclosed area between $y=\frac{3x}{5π}$ and the curve $y=\sin x$ for $0≤x≤π$ shown shaded in the diagram.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, solution-verification, area, trigonometric-integrals

> The diagram shows the line $y=\frac{3x}{5\pi}$ and the curve $y=\sin$
> $x$ for $0\le x\le \pi$.
>
> Find (as an exact value) the enclosed area shown shaded in the diagram.

[image]

I'm not sure where I've made an error, but this is my working out so far:

Area under $y=\frac{3x}{5\pi}$ from $0$ to $\frac{5\pi}{6}$ is:

$$\int_{0}^{5\pi/6} \frac{3x}{5\pi}dx=\frac{5\pi}{24}$$

The remaining **unshaded** "triangle" area from $\frac{5\pi}{6}$  to $\pi$:

$$\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{\pi}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{\pi}{24}$$

Area under $y=\sin x$ for $0\le x\le\pi$:

$$\int_{0}^{\pi} \sin{x}dx=2$$

Hence, shaded area = $$2-\frac{5\pi}{24} - \frac{\pi}{24} = \frac{-\pi}{4} + 2$$

The **correct** answer is:

$$1+\frac{\sqrt3}{2} - \frac{5\pi}{24} units^2$$

If someone could explain how to correctly solve this, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That unshaded area is not a triangle! And moreover, you don't need to consider that. Just subtract the first expression from the area under $\sin x$ in the range $[0, 5\pi/6]$, that is, $\int_{0}^{5\pi/6} \sin x dx$, which should give you the required expression directly ,without even bothering about the "triangle".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The area under $sin(x)$ between $x=5 \pi/6$ and $x=\pi$ is **not** a triangle. The top part is not a straight line, but $sin(x)$- which is curved. to find the area, you can integrate:

$$
\int_{5 \pi/6}^{\pi} sin(x) dx
$$

Answer (score 0):

The unshaded area from $5\pi/6$ to $\pi$ is not a triangle! It should be instead $$\int_{5\pi/6}^{\pi} \sin x \ dx =1-\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

May be more easy is to calcualte
$$\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{5\pi}{6}}\int\limits_{\frac{3x}{5\pi}}^{\sin x}dxdy=\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{5\pi}{6}}\left(\sin x - \frac{3x}{5\pi} \right)dx=1+\frac{\sqrt3}{2} - \frac{5\pi}{24} $$

Comment: Most probably the OP hasn't yet studied multivaried function and double integrals.

Comment: @DonAntonio. May be. Anyway second integral is for sure in OP knowledge area and gives more easy way. And, also, first term gives view, that there is some more powerful tools in mathematics.